# How use a script DOM element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, dom

How do I change the script tag with a script DOM? Previously I used a script like this

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

But I want to use the script DOM. when I change like this, script not working

```
<script>
var jquerymin = document.createElement('script');
jquerymin.type = 'text/javascript';
jquerymin.async = true;
jquerymin.src = 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.2.min.js';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jquerymin);

var jqueryui = document.createElement('script');
jqueryui.type = 'text/javascript';
jqueryui.async = true;
jqueryui.src = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jqueryui);
</script>
```

Is DOM script, cant run script *jquery.min* and *jquery.ui*?

Comment: what do you mean script not working ? Are you waiting for their load event before doing anything with their content ? Btw, since jqueryUI needs jquery, you may want to wrap the creation of its node only when the jquerymin load event has fired.

Comment: How change this code `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.2.min.js"></script>` with DOM?

Comment: jsut as you did does work, but you'll have to wait for the scripts have loaded (`jquerymin.onload=function(){doSomethingWith$()}`) before you're actually able to use there content scripts.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use pure Javascript to add (asynchronously) a new script file, you can do this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>JS</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var 
                scriptElement,
                script;

            scriptElement = document.createElement('script'); 
            scriptElement.src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.2.min.js";

            script = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            script.parentNode.insertBefore(scriptElement, script);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: But if I want to enter the code `https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.2.min.js`. not successful. Is `https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.2.min.js` code can **only** be run with the code `<script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.2.min.js "> </ script>` ???

Comment: sure i change `http://example.com/script.js` with `https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.2.min.js` but still not working?

Comment: I have replaced `http://example.com/script.js` with `https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.2.min.js` and jquery resource file appeared. Can you double check your code?

Comment: Please copy all my HTML code and check It again. I have made there some changes.

Comment: Save my code in separated html file and run It. You will see that my code works good.